# Don't understand (variableName != "") in JavaScript code - Coderbyte Challenge #25: NumberSearch

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am having difficulty analyzing a line of someone else's JS code for a Coderbyte challenge. We are to search for all numbers in a given string, add them together, and then return the final sum. So "88Hello 3World!" should have an output of 91. "55Hello" should have an output of 55. And "5Hello 5" should output 10. The line of code I'm having difficulty interpreting specifically says:

```
else if (curNum != "") {
```

Please help me understand, what this line, specifically, is doing in the context of the entire function. What does it accomplish? When would curNum === ""? Could you give an example? The line is taken from the following code:

```
function NumberAddition(str) {

var result = 0;                               //creates var result; sets value to 0
var curNum = "";                              //creates var curNum; sets value to ""

for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {       //run thru user-inputted string, for each character...
  if (str[i] >= "0" && str[i] <= "9") {      //if the current element is b/w 0 and 9... 
    curNum += str[i];                        //add the value of that element (as a string) to curNum
 else if (curNum != "")                    ***   // ***the 1st part of the if statement is relevant if str[i] is a number. What does this else-if branch do and when does it apply???!
    result += parseInt(curNum);              // convert curNum to an integer and add it to result variable
    curNum = "";                             // reset curNum variable to "" / blank
  }
}

if (curNum != "")                       ***   // *** again, when does this apply?
  result += parseInt(curNum);              // take whatever's in curNum and convert to an integer and add to result variable
}

return result;                             //return result after running thru entire for-loop
}
```

If I were to take a stab at it (reading b/w the lines), the line of code will apply when str[i] is not a number, so that the value currently in curNum is converted to a string as soon as str[i] is a character other than a number? Not sure if that makes sense though. But I guess what I'm asking, is what exactly is

```
curNum != ""
```

saying??? And can you please show an example of how it works and when it applies (both uses of it)?...

Comment: If it's not an empty string !

Comment: ok so what does that mean though and what exactly does that line of code do?

Comment: It checks if curNum is not an empty string, and that's all it does, there's no magic going on.

Comment: essentially it is making sure `curName` has a value before running `parseInt` on it to avoid errors.

Comment: At first do you know what [strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) are in programming? if not, it's sequence of characters or just TEXT. Second, [Logical not or unary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2FLogical_Operators#Logical_NOT_.28.21.29) `!` it's just negation operator, so returns false if its single operand can be converted to true; otherwise, returns true.

Comment: yea i understand what strings are givi. thanks for the gracious and constructive comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`curNum` inside the for will be filled with 1 digit at a time, untill it contains all the characters in a number. At that point, the number will be added to the result and `curNum` will be reset to the empty string.

When iterating over `abc`, the if condition

```
if (str[i] >= "0" && str[i] <= "9") {
```

will fail, going on the else branch. On the else branch, curNum will be checked if it has a value and that check will also fail, so nothing happens, curNum remains `''`.

When iterating over `123`, the if condition will always match, and curNum will successivly be be `1`, `12`, `123`.

Finally, when another letter is encountered `123x`, on the `x` the condition will fail, going on the else branch. On it curNum will indeed have a value (`123`), so the value will be parsed as an integer and added to the result.

A similar check is made after the string has been iterated over, in case there were numbers at the end.

Answer (score 0):

If this never evaluates to true

```
  if (str[i] >= "0" && str[i] <= "9")
```

Then curNum will be empty. The condition checks to see if CurNum is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

If value of variable **str** ends with number (example: Test_1) then your loop will be finished on this code

```
if (str[i] >= "0" && str[i] <= "9") {      //if the current element is b/w 0 and 9... 
    curNum += str[i];
```

and then this code return true (curNum != "")

P.S. Sory for my poor english

Comment: Thank you. So if my question receives negative points does that mean it's a stupid question? If it's a stupid question, I apologize. No not really tho. I actually don't apologize. It's called I'm learning...

Answer (score 0):

Ok.

```
if (str[i] >= "0" && str[i] <= "9") {
     // If currently value is between 0 and 9
     // Assign curnum
} elseif (curNum != "")  {
     // If curnum has a value then parse the integer value.
}
```

I would suggest using a regex to parse out numberic values from your string. Fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/5qf7q/15/

Comment: Thank you for the regex example captain John. I am still banging my head against the wall trying to learn regex's. If you know of any great tutorials, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx has all the information you need. Regexs are very hard to follow, so trying them out and using existing one;'s people have developed is the way to go.

Comment: Once you begin to get a grasp of regex from a tutorial, this regex builder / tester might also come in handy: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/